# Filters formula fields smartGWT13

Tags: java, smartgwt

I have a test environment with the BuiltInDs project that uses the following components:

- JDK 1.8
- SmartGWT Eval v13.0p_2023-08-16

In the BuiltInDs project we added a formula field and modified the setCanFilter attribute so that it can be filtered, but when we try to filter and switch to another field we get a dot in the formula field filter.
Here I attach a video of the behavior and the part of the code where we add the new field:

[FormulaField](https://youtu.be/yW_G9Gk0h3w)

[image: Code]